# Is it possible to retrieve a document from Cloud Storage from linux shell script?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage

I am currently working on an personal application where, I upload documents/pictures/videos from my phone to Cloud Storage. During this time my computer sitting at home is consistently running a shell script waiting for a new document to be uploaded to Cloud Storage, after it finds an uploaded file, it downloads it does some work to it, and then deletes it.

I can figure out how to upload and connect my application to Firebase, but I am not sure if its possible for a shell script to do the remaining work.

Should I look into some other service to do this, or another method?

thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you mean "Cloud Firestore" instead of "Firebase Cloud Store"?

Comment: @DougStevenson On the Firebase site under products, it states Firebase Cloud Store. But I'm simply asking for any form of database on Firebase.

Comment: Can you point me to the documentation that shows what you're describing?  That's definitely not the correct name of the product.

Comment: Or maybe you're talking about Cloud Storage, which is not a database?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/

Comment: Sorry you are correct, I mean Firestore.

Comment: That link you provided goes to Cloud Storage.  Are you saying you want to read and write files in Cloud Storage from a shell?

Comment: Thank you for the response, and that is essentially what I would like to do, except I would like to upload files from my phone, and have the bash shell script just retrieve them and store them to my personal computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a command line program called [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) to upload and download files from a Cloud Storage bucket.  This should be easy to use from a shell script.